# How can I access this value in a pivot table (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm putting together a simple shopping cart system, using Laravel and Vue.js, to sell photos. Each photo comes in a range of sizes, with the price of each size being different.

I have the following tables:

```
Photos
 - id
 - title

Sizes
 - id
 - dimensions

Photos_Sizes
 - id
 - photo_id
 - size_id
 - price
```

I'm using Vue.js to make API calls to my cart controller to manipulate the cart. It passes the photo_id and size_id when the user clicks the Add to Basket button. Naturally I want to grab the price of a selected item from the database rather than client side to prevent any cheekiness, and that naturally means querying the pivot table.

My question is, using the two ids passed to the controller, how can I access the correct price value in the pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query Builder in your controller like this:

```
public function price(Request $request)
{

    $row = DB::table('Photos_Sizes')
        ->where('photo_id', $request->input('photo_id'))
        ->where('size_id', $request->input('size_id'))
        ->first();

    return Response::create($row->price, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the relationships for both Photos and Sizes, add `->withPivot('price')` Then once you have your result set, you can access the field with `$size->pivot->price`

Comment: I have already set up my models with the price pivot. I guess my question is how do I actually _get_ the result set in the first place, that I can then access with $size->pivot->price?

Comment: If you have single object then yes, otherwise you need to loop through collection first.